# Where should I set the variable PATH in R?

Tags: r, environment-variables

I constantly need to call Tex Live binaries for compilation in R. However after the upgrade of Tex Live distribution, the path to current binaries needed to updated manually in the `PATH`(`Sys.getenv("PATH")`) variable.

As a single user on a Ubuntu system, which file should I update the value in, so that R gets the `PATH` correctly irrespective of whichever directory R is launched from.

One point I still don't gather is from where does `R` gets its site-wide (I mean for all users, even if faulty in saying so) `PATH` variable set, because no such variable name as "PATH" occur inside any files (Renviron, Renviron.site, Rprofile.site) in either of "R_HOME/etc/" and user's home directory? I also haven't set `Sys.getenv("R_ENVIRON")` and `Sys.getenv("R_ENVIRON_USER")` values.

I'd appreciate anybody's input here.

Comment: The `PATH` variable can be set for your whole Ubuntu system, and is really more of an Ubuntu thing than something specific to R, hence why it doesn't show up in files like Renviron. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path

Comment: PS: I would recommend the answer that suggests editing `~/.profile` rather than the other suggestions.

Comment: Agreed this is an Ubuntu question, not an R question. Add something like `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux:$PATH` to `~/.profile` (modify for your specific case if required).

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the bash environment variables are not shared with R. I have set my PATH variable from .Rprofile.

Comment: @42- using `~/.profile` should ensure that the environment variables are properly set system-wide, rather than just for bash. Other options like `.bashrc` are bash specific.

Comment: @Marius Thanks for guiding. I wished to know where _system-wide_ `PATH` is defined and I now know that it resides in `/etc/environment` file. That's one way to solve which I thinks works best for me.

Comment: @42- Exactly! That happens to be the case with `.bashrc`. The `PATH` variable values are loaded in from the .bashrc whenever I launched `R` from the shell. Unfortunately, It's not the same for rstudio non-shell sessions.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks for the suggestion. But, for a rstudio session, run in desktop environment, It seems that by default variables defined in `~/.profile` are not shared.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I have a .profile on an Ubuntu server containing the line `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` and I see that directory appended to PATH when I run `Sys.getenv()` in RStudio desktop on that server. Perhaps you need to `source ~/.profile` after editing or try logging in again?

Comment: @neilfws this is not out of the box behavior for R

Answer (score 5):

@JeffreyGoldberg's solution was close, but not quite right.

`Rprofile` files are interpreted as R code
`Renviron` files can only contain name value pairs, and are **not** interpreted as R code

From the help for Startup:

> Note that there are two sorts of files used in startup: environment files which contain lists of environment variables to be set, and profile files which contain R code.

I'm not sure if this question is asking specifically how one can set the **site wide** value of `PATH`, rather than `PATH` for one specific user, but there are three locations you can put these files.

1. A project directory (i.e., a directory you choose to launch R from)
2. `HOME`
3. `R_HOME/etc`

These locations are searched in the order numbered above. The first location can contain configurations specific to a project, the second contains those specific to a user, and the third, site wide configuration settings. When a file is found it is used, so local takes precedence over global. Don't think you can create a more specific version that simply updates what you've done in a more general configuration file.  `R_HOME/etc/Renviron` is created on installation and should not be edited. You may create a file called `R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site`, but do not edit `R_HOME/etc/Renviron`.

To create a site wide value of PATH, you will want to set it in a file in `R_HOME/etc`. Here you can use either `Renviron.site` or `Rprofile.site` for the file name. For a file in `R_HOME/etc`, Do not use `Renviron`, `Rprofile`, `.Renviron`, or `.Rprofile` for the name of a profile or environment file in this location. You can find out what R_HOME is in an R session using `R.home()`, or `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")`

To create a PATH value for a single user, set it in a file in `HOME`, which you can find in your R session using `Sys.getenv("HOME")` or `path.expand("~")`. You can also just use "~" to refer to `HOME`. Here, an Renviron file should be `~/.Renviron`and an Rprofile file `~/.Rprofile`. Take note of the difference between how profile and environment files are named in your `HOME` directory vs. `R_HOME/etc`

To create a PATH for a single project, set it in a file in that project's top level directory. Name the files as you would in your home directory (`.Rprofile` or `.Renviron`).

If you are creating an Renviron file, the file should include the following line:

```
PATH=<your path>
```

`<` and `>` should not be included. An example would be:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If you are creating an Rprofile file, the file should include the following line:

```
Sys.setenv("<your path>")
```

again, don't include "<" or ">". An example would be:

```
Sys.setenv("/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin")
```

There are various ways of doing this that get and edit a PATH variable (e.g., tack on a new path at the end, or the beginning). You can also use the strategy of setting an environment variable if it doesn't already exist and/or doesn't contain something you want it to. I've come to prefer just setting up my path simply, and coding it directly.

One final note, if you run `R` from a command line interface, environment variables may be inherited from your shell. RStudio also has its own startup sequence and may modify the end of your PATH variable. It should start as it is defined in your Rprofile or Renviron files. The R Console app itself has the fewest quirks with system environment variables, and should accept your path exactly as it is set with an Rprofile or Renviron file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I should have tested before posting. What I describe below did *not* work. (Down voting my own answer is a strange thing.)

On my system (macOS, bash), R.app is not picking up my `$PATH` from my shell environment or `.profile`. However RStudio is picking it up. I do not understand the different behaviors.

One way to get consistent behavior would be to specify this in an Renviron file.

If you create a file named `.Renviron` in your come directory with a line like

`Sys.setenv(PATH="/opt/local/bin:usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin")`

(but of course with the path elements you need) that should give you consistent behavior.

The downside is that you need to manually maintain this. I suppose you could run a script from one of your other start up scripts that generated the `.Renviron` file. But either way, I consider this whole thing a work around in place of actually understanding where R picks up its environment from.