# How to Set external variable or program for Rstudio

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I know that this question is available in this page, but I have tried most of them, and I just can’t make it works. How can I set an external program as blast permanently using Sys.setenv  for my personal functions in R

I’m using a MacOS with R4.1.1 and RStudio 2021.09.0.

The common way that I usually call an external program, in this case BLAST (ncbi-blast-2.2.29+) is just copy and paste the line in RStudio console, something like:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/Users/myname/myprograms/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/bin/", sep= .Platform$path.sep))
```

And then I just run my personal functions that use blast, and I have no problem with that.  But I just want to set blast permanently in RStudio, and don’t need to copy and paste that line every time that I start RStudio. So I tried to paste that line in .Renviron, and then start up Rstudio and tried to run blast functions, and it didn’t work !!!

So I tried different, add the path in .zshrc (I’m using /bin/zsh), using nano or sublime text:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
export BLAST_PATH=$PATH:~/genetools/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/bin/
```

And then just add the BLAST_PATH to Sys.setenv in .Renviron

```
nano .Renviron

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "BLAST_PATH", sep= .Platform$path.sep))
```

or

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), BLAST_PATH, sep= .Platform$path.sep))
```

And restart RStudio and just it didn’t work when I use my personal functions !!!

Any way to set it permanently in RStudio ?

By the way, My .Renviron is located at home (~/.Renviron) and my working directory (R sessions ) in RStudio is located in ~/R !!!

Thanks

Comment: Environment variables for a user has nothing to do with R. You need to set the variables in your pc. check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables for example on how to do it in linux, and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable on windows

Comment: @Onyambu Except that these solutions categorically do not work for RStudio (or any other GUI applications) on macOS.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I specified that you do not necessarily need to use R. Setting environment variable has nothing to do with R. I am not sure about macOs. As far as I know, in windows, one cam simply use `setx` command, or just search for environment variables from the search button and set them the way they want

Comment: @Onyambu But as my answer shows *there is no good non-R way to do this on macOS*. You need R (specifically, `.Renviron`). So the question, for better or for worse, *does* have to do with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, `.Renviron` does not expect R code but rather shell-like variable assignments. So you could add the following to your `.Renviron`:

```bash
PATH=~/genetools/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/bin/:$PATH
```

You could also adjust your `PATH` inside `.zshrc`, but unfortunately RStudio *will not see these values!* Unless, that is, you are actually starting RStudio from inside your zsh, for instance via `open -a RStudio`. Only then will it work.

In general, applications only inherit the shell environment when they are launched *from the shell*, and `.zshrc` is only sourced by your zsh. This means that it cannot be used to set global configuration for applications on macOS. [In earlier versions of macOS it was possible to configure the launch daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385934/1968) (which is the background application that is launching all GUI applications on macOS). However, this no longer works because Apple disabled the mechanism.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there is *no way* to configure the global environment for GUI applications on macOS any more. All the different hacks that are documented on Stack Overflow fail. The only way is via running `launchctl setenv …` at every startup.

Comment: thanks so much to all, it just didn't work for me, but I  will try again, thanks so much anyway !!!!

Answer (score 3):

`.Renviron` does not accept "R code". You can check what's happening for example with calling [`readRenviron("~/.Renviron")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRenviron.html).
You could follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55177322/1216790) route inside `.Renviron` or just put your code (above) in an `.Rprofile` file either in your `$R_USER` or project directory, depending on your requirements, ie if you want to have those ENV variables "project specific" or not.
Details on the startup process can be found in the [R manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) or for example in the [`startup`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html) package documentation, [startup package] also adds some nice functionality in case you need to handle passwords or other things along the "way" [ie. the startup process].